# Evaluate double integral $\iint_R\sqrt \frac{x+y}{x-2y}dA$ using change of variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Evaluate the integral
$$\iint_R\sqrt \frac{x+y}{x-2y}dA$$
where $R$ is the region bounded by $ y - \frac{x}{2} = 0, y = 0,x+y = 1.$

I know I need to change the variable to $u$ and $v$, since that is the related section to this problem, and also use the Jacobian, but I am not sure where to start.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you stuck with? Use $u = x+y, v = x-2y$. Can you find Jacobian of transformation? Can you find limits of integral?

Comment: You have posted the question without any context and I have not heard back where you are really stuck. Just saying "I am not sure where to start" does not help anyone. If you show efforts from your side, I will help you. For now, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I decided to post my answer because a full answer was already given, but for future reference you really should give more context to the question, and show what you've tried. Your question will likely get a much better response that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's probably how they wanted you to do it: let's use the transformation $u = x + y, v = x - 2y.$ Solving the system of equations for $x$ and $y$ gives us the reverse transformation $x = \frac13(2u + v), y = \frac13(u-v).$

In order to change variables like this, we have to transform the domain of integration as well. I'm going to do this by choosing $v$ to be bounded by two constants and $u$ be bounded by functions of $v.$ So $v$ will go from $0$ ($x - 2y = v = 0$) to $1.$ (at $(1,0)$) $u$ will now go from the line $y = \frac13(u-v) = 0$ up to $x + y = u = 1.$ So, rewriting our bounds of integration should be

$$\bar{R} = \{(u,v): v \leq u \leq 1, 0 \leq v \leq 1\}$$

Now the next thing we have to do to is calculate the determinant of the Jacobian of our transformation. We can do this as follows:

$$|J| = \begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}\frac23 & \frac13 \\ \frac13 & -\frac13\end{vmatrix} = -\frac13$$

So, we can now rewrite our integral as follows:

$$\iint_R \sqrt{\frac{x+y}{x-2y}} dA = \iint_{\bar{R}} \sqrt{\frac{u}{v}} \cdot \left|-\frac{1}{3}\right| du dv = \frac13\int_0^1\int_v^1 \sqrt{\frac{u}{v}} du dv$$

We can now integrate as follows:

$$\frac13\int_0^1 v^{-\frac12} \int_v^1 u^{\frac12} du dv = \frac13\cdot\frac23\int_0^1 v^{-\frac12}\left(1 - v^{\frac32}\right) dv = \frac29 \int_0^1 v^{-1/2} - v dv$$

Noting that our integral is improper: (it always has been)

$$\lim_{a\to 0} \frac29 \int_a^1 v^{-\frac12} - v dv = \frac29 \lim_{a \to 0} 2\sqrt{v} - \frac12v^2\Bigg|_a^1 = \frac29 \lim_{a \to 0} \left(\frac32 - 2\sqrt{a} + \frac12a^2\right) = \boxed{\frac13}$$

Answer (score 0):

Change the base to polar coordinates, i.e. $x=r\cos t$ and $ y= r\sin t$

\begin{align}
&\iint_R\sqrt \frac{x+y}{x-2y}dxdy 
=\int_0^{\tan^{-1}\frac12}\int_0^{\frac1{\cos t +\sin t}}
\sqrt \frac{\cos t+\sin t}{\cos t-2\sin t}\>rdr dt\\
&\hspace{15mm}=\int_0^{\tan^{-1}\frac12}
\frac{\frac1{2(\cos t+\sin t)^2}} {\sqrt \frac {\cos t-2\sin t} {\cos t+\sin t}}dt
 =-\int_0^{\tan^{-1}\frac12}
\frac {d\left(\frac{\cos t-2\sin t} {\cos t+\sin t}\right)}{6\sqrt \frac{\cos t-2\sin t} {\cos t+\sin t}}
=\frac13
\end{align}

Comment: Yeah you can do that... but why.

Comment: Both the integrand and the integral region are suitable for polar coordinates.

Comment: Frankly, I disagree